# How to target ::before pseudo element with :not(:focus):valid?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to use just CSS for this so please bear with me.

I have this structure:

```
<div class="form-element">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

The CSS for showing the placeholders, and animating them when user clicks into the input is:

```
.form-element
    &:before
        content: "test"
        top: 0
    &:focus-within
        &:before
            top: 5px
```

So, now I need to use :not(:focus):valid for the inputs, so the labels would stay at top: 5px when user insert content into the input but click outside of the input.

Is this possible to do? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
.form-element
    &:before
        content: "test"
        top: 0
    &:focus-within
        &:before
            top: 5px
    input
        &:not(:focus):valid
            ~ &:before
                    top: 10px
                    left: 20px
                    font-size: 0.9em
                    font-weight: lighter
```

Here is the current version I'm at: https://codepen.io/cungalunga/pen/zWZwwY, so what I need now, I want the placeholder to stay at the top when there is content in the input and when user clicks outside of the .form-element itself.

Comment: You should really post a working demo using compiled CSS so we can all understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/cungalunga/pen/zWZwwY

Comment: `~` matches siblings. You are trying to target :before the label which is the *parent* (not a sibling) of the input. See the duplicate question.

Comment: If you can change the HTML... [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/XEMRBm?editors=1100)

Comment: Nope, can't alter the html...